# Iterate rows and find sum of rows not exceeding a number

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a dataframe showing coordinate values from and to, each row having a corresponding value column.

I want to find the range of coordinates where the value column doesn't exceed 5. Below is the dataframe input.

```
import pandas as pd

From=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]
to=[20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
value=[2,3,5,6,1,3,1]


df=pd.DataFrame({'from':From, 'to':to, 'value':value})
print(df)
```

hence I want to convert the following table:

[image]

to the following outcome:

[image]

Further explanation:

1. Coordinates from 10 to 30 are joined and the value column changed to 5
   as its sum of values from 10 to 30 (not exceeding 5)
2. Coordinates 30 to 40 equals 5
3. Coordinate 40 to 50 equals 6 (more than 5, however, it's included as it cannot be divided further)
4. Remaining coordinates sum up to a value of 5

What code is required to achieve the above?

Comment: what if they exceed 5 on adding next num. let's say Curr_sum=4 and next value is 5, then aggregate is 9, then what should be the answer in this case?

Answer (score 3):

We can do a groupby on cumsum:

```
s = df['value'].ge(5)
(df.groupby([~s, s.cumsum()], as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({'from':'min','to':'max', 'value':'sum'})
)
```

Output:

```
   from  to  value
0    10  30      5
1    30  40      5
2    40  50      6
3    50  80      5
```

---

**Update:** It looks like you want to accumulate the values so the new groups do not exceed `5`. There are several threads on SO saying that this can only be done with a for a loop. So we can do something like this:

```
thresh = 5

groups, partial, curr_grp = [], thresh, 0
for v in df['value']:
    if partial + v > thresh:
        curr_grp += 1
        partial = v
    else:
        partial += v

    groups.append(curr_grp)

df.groupby(groups).agg({'from':'min','to':'max', 'value':'sum'})
```

Comment: @TheOracle actually, after reading your question again, this might not be what you need. This group **all** consecutive values that are `<5`, so some of the group can exceed `5` by a lot. For example if we have `3 4 3`, this solution gives you one group, while you may want 2 groups.